# How to make a list of element draggable and sortable using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-draggable

I have a list of element, I want to make it sortable and draggable using Jquery. But when we dragg the particular element, it should not overlap to other existing element.Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

 $(function() {

$( ".abc" ).draggable();

});

</script>
<ul>
<li class="abc"> 1 </li>
<li class="abc"> 2 </li>
<li class="abc"> 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, we need both features(sortable & draggable) to the list of elements at a time.

Comment: Try the another answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(function() {
$( ".abc" ).draggable({
connectToSortable: "#sortable",
revert: "invalid"
});
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
   revert: true
});
 $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="abc"> 1 </li>
<li class="abc"> 2 </li>
<li class="abc"> 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I sort it, it becomes overlap with others

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable : This example works fine with both draggable & sortable without overlapping.